# URGENT:How to keep using SDK after IDE has been expired (FlashBuilder4Force.com)

Tags: flex3, flex4, flexbuilder, flash-builder

I was using Flash builder for force .com IDE for my project but it has been expired.

Can I only use its SDK which I think should be free and compile my application using command prompt.

I know how to compile mxml applications from command line in simple flex application but for Force.com projects I am stuck.

I have copied all the swc in libs folder.

The compiler throws an error 'Error: could not resolve  'flexforforce:F3WebApplication' to a component implementation. '.

Can any one help me here?  I don't know how to proceed from here :(
Thanks in advence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the true command-line parameters with the -dump-config option (see http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Compiling_Flex_libraries_with_Ant-16504.html)

Cheers